# Second SQL query not running

Tags: java, sqlite

```
private void signoutbutton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String sql = "select * from userlogin where Username=? and Password=? and Hasmac='false'  and Blacklisted='false' and Level='student' or Level='teacher' or Level='admin'";
    try {
        String value6 = txt_sou.getText();

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_sou.getText());
        pst.setString(2, signoutpassword.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
             //this sql query will not run// 
             sql = "update userlogin set Hasmac='true' where username='" + value6 + "'";
            //yet this runs//
            this.dispose();

            {



            }
        } else {
            errorsignout.setText("Error: User Information Not Found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question, you should add more explanation, how did you notice the error, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second assignment to `sql` just changes the value of that string variable.

To execute an SQL statement, you have to call `prepareStatement` to get a statement object, and call `executeUpdate` on that.

Comment: thank you so much @peter should have seen the that but now it works and i can continue                                                                                 thanks again matthew